# make exception for BBCodes when use htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, html, special-characters, bbcode

i used htmlspecialchars to clean site comments, it's change `<>` to html special character. but i also need to put some links in comments, same like as here at SO.
i think some thing like perg_replace can make a exception for htmlspecialchars, for example to hide [`LINK]<a href="...">...</a>[/LINK]` from htmlspecialchars. how i can make it in php? or what's a better way to do that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
$comment = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote('[link]','/').'(.*?)'.preg_quote('[/link]','/').'/eisU',"htmlspecialchars_decode('$1')", $comment);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a library for parsing BBCode or similar things - and generally speaking that would sanitise the input itself. A quick google turned up [NBBC](http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/), although that might be a bit overkill for your purposes. You don't even need to use BBCode, unless you've got your heart set on it - there are perfectly good PHP libraries for [Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) and the like.